# Align Text in Navigation

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, header-footer

I have a beamer template with following code:

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.24\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
  \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfill\hskip-17ex\insertsectionnavigation{.22\paperwidth}\vfill\hfill}%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.24\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
  \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsubsectionnavigation{.18\paperwidth}\vfil}%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.038\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
  \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\hspace*{0.6cm}\pgfuseimage{UT}\vfil}%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
```

Thats the header.... My problem is, that the text of the Navigation doenst start left align. I want the text all the way to the left in the box. The text always starts always in the middle of the box and kinda types backwards. Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `\insertsubsection` instead of `\insertsubsectionnavigation{⟨width⟩}` which according to the manual

> Inserts a vertical navigation bar containing all subsections
>   of the current section, with the current subsection highlighted.

This bar adds additional space to the left and right of the (sub)section. It works the same way with `\insertsection` versus `\insertsectionnavigation{⟨width⟩}`.

Please compare with this example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.24\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
  \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfill\insertsection\vfill\hfill}%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.24\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
  \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsubsection\vfil}%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.038\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
  \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\hspace*{0.6cm}\rule{2cm}{0.5cm}\vfil}%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{frame}{A show frame}
just text here
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Comments:** 
Now that the text directly starts at the frame border, you might want to insert a `\hspace*{1em}`.

I removed `\hskip-17ex` in order to render the text within the `beamercolorbox` and used a rule instead of the UT image.

**Update:**

Alternatively, you can redefine the templates of `\insertsectionnavigation`and `\insertsubsectionnavigation` from `beamerbasenavigation.sty` for a reduction of the added horizontal space and `\RaggedRight` text (using the `ragged2e` package).

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\insertsectionnavigation[1]{%
  \hbox to #1{%
    \vbox{{\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
     \vskip0.5ex%
     \def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{}%
     \def\sectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{%
       \ifnum##5=\c@part%
       \def\insertsectionhead{##2}%
       \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##1}%
       \def\insertpartheadnumber{##5}%
       \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\RaggedRight% added for flushed left text
         \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{\hbox to #1{%
             \hskip0.5ex% adjusted from 0.3 cm
             \ifnum\c@section=##1%
               {\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}}%
             \else%
               {\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}}%
             \fi\hskip0.5ex}}}% adjusted from 0.3 cm
       \ht\beamer@tempbox=1.6875ex\dp\beamer@tempbox=0.75ex%
       \box\beamer@tempbox\fi}%
     \dohead\vskip0.5ex}}\hfil}}
\renewcommand\insertsubsectionnavigation[1]{%
  \hbox to #1{%
    \vbox{{%
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vskip0.5625ex%
      \beamer@currentsubsection=0%
      \def\sectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{}%
      \def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{\ifnum##6=\c@part\ifnum##1=\c@section%
        \ifnum##2>\beamer@currentsubsection%
        \beamer@currentsubsection=##2%
        \def\insertsubsectionhead{##5}%
        \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##1}%
        \def\insertsubsectionheadnumber{##2}%
        \def\insertpartheadnumber{##6}%
        \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\RaggedRight\beamer@link(##4){% added for flushed left text
            \hbox to #1{\hskip0.5ex% adjusted from 0.3 cm
              \ifnum\c@subsection=##2%
                {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot}}%
              \else%
                {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot shaded}}%
              \fi\hfil\hskip0.5ex}}}% adjusted from 0.3 cm
        \ht\beamer@tempbox=1.6875ex\dp\beamer@tempbox=0.75ex%
        \box\beamer@tempbox\fi\fi\fi}%
      \dohead\vskip0.5625ex}\hfil}}}
% headline template     
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.24\paperwidth]{section in head/foot}%
\insertsectionnavigation{.22\paperwidth}%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.24\paperwidth]{section in head/foot}%
\insertsubsectionnavigation{.18\paperwidth}%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.038\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
  \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\hspace*{0.6cm}\rule{2cm}{0.5cm}\vfil}%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: But the problem is, that its shows just the actual Section which is active. I wanna see the other ones too...

Comment: @ben: please see my updated answer!

Comment: If I add your code to my *.sty File I'll get an error:
! Undefined control sequence.
l.171 \ifbeamer
               @compress
?

Comment: @ben did you use the enclosing `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` commands? Is your LaTeX-system up-to-date?